# How can I get GitHub's files with a specific extension?

Tags: github

I am working on a project about R's language syntax and I want to retrieve as many as possible `*.R` extension files from GitHub. I couldn't figure it out myself at the GitHub's API tool nor with custom search engines such as Google's and Bing's. Any input would be vastly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using this keyword in Google custom search engine:

> site:github.com filetype:r

For example you want to search any r file related to **Anova** in github.com. So open google.com and type this keyword:

> anova site:github.com filetype:r

Comment: Awesome what I did was to replace the `github.com` with `raw.githubusercontent.com` to retrieve the raw code.